# What is the origin of the phrase 'By Jove;?

Tags: etymology

The question is above. As in, the sentence 'By Jove, he is running away!'

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you about Jove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a  minced oath,  a way to avoid referencing the sacred or profane, such as God or Jesus, or calling on the devil. Apparently its earliest usage dates back to  the 16th century. Note that the expression is  sort of  outdated and its usage is clearly decreasing,  see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by%20Jove&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cby%20Jove%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBy%20Jove%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bby%20Jove%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBy%20jove%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bby%20jove%3B%2Cc0).

> - It's an age-old way to dance around what was considered blasphemous -- that is, using the Lord's name as a profanity, or naming the devil -- or to side-step outright swearing with euphemisms, especially when startled or annoyed.
> - “By Jove” (or “by Jupiter”) was not a euphemism when it first showed up in English; it originally referred directly to the Roman deity. ***The OED’s earliest example for “by Jove” uses the term in reference to the Roman god, in Apius and Virginia, an anonymous 1575 play set in classical times***.

(Quora)

Shakespeare used it in Love’s Labours Lost in 1588: “By Jove, I always took three threes for nine”.

***[By Jove](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/by--jove)***:

> - Also, by cracky. Used to express surprise or emphasis. For example, By Jove, I was glad to see her, or It was a great day, by cracky. These mild oaths are euphemisms, the first for “by Jesus” or “by God” ***(Jove is another name for Jupiter, the principal Roman god)***, and the folksy variant by cracky for “by Christ.” Both idioms may be dying out.

(AHD)